# Lifetime of flat panel monitor - Taking into account dimming and not just stop working

Tags: display, lcd

I have been told by somewhat of an expert at my company that in an office setting the current flat panel monitors usually have a lifetime of around 3-5 years.  The context of this is not that they will stop working after 3-5 years.  The context is that they will dim over time and after 3-5 years the dimming will be enough that it will lead to things like eye strain and backstrain (from leaning closer to the monitor).

Is this true?  I can't seem to find any information on this.

Answer (score 3):

This is possibly true.. for some panels at least.  I have a panel attached to an old dev box which is 7 years old and works absolutely fine!

However, TFTCentral says:

> The main area to consider really here is the backlight. TFT’s are backlit using CCFL lamps, and these typically have a life expectancy of >40,000hrs. To give you an idea that would be 4.5yrs of the panel being on 24/7 or 9yrs with a more realistic 12/7. Basically by the time the TFT has had it’s better days, you will probably be wanting to buy a new one anyway.

Generally, however, you will find that a manufacturers life expectancy for their products will not be right.  In experience as someone who used to work at a manufacturer, lots of companies will give a slightly shorter than real life expectancy (backed by warranty).  That way, if a product fails, there is more chance it is out of warranty - which also looks good on the company when a product with a 3 year expected life lasts 5 or 10 years!

Comment: Thanks for the info but I have a follow up.  How do you know the 7 year old monitor is working absolutely fine?  My question is asking about things that are not obvious.  You may look at a monitor and think it looks fine but you also may have eye strain and lean closer to your monitor to see, and not even know you're doing it.

Comment: for me its simple.. I can still read it in daylight from nearly 15 feet across a room with no problems.  If you wanted to test properly to ensue there had been no deterioration, you would need to either use a light meter to test the lumen count of the screen at various intervals I guess, although I am not an expert on how exactly these measurements are taken.  I think someone else may be better suited to answer your followup